# NetSuite - I want to create a new page as same as SO

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm an newbie in NetSuite field and I'm trying to improve my tech capabilities.
Recently, I decide to develop a page as same as SO.
But I can't find the starting point.
If someone has an extensive experience in NetSuite, please let me know the solution.

I'm researching several docs but no result

Answer (score 0):

I am confused with the question .

If you want to create a transaction like a sales order then you need to create a new transaction type through customization .

If you want to create pages , Input forms , custom forms etc , you can make a suitelet or a portlet depending what your purpose is .

If you want to store data you can create a custom record .

What you see on the sales order is a form , a form is how Netsuite structures the information for you to enter and when you enter this information it stores it to the DB in the form of a record .